# A webpage in which on each refresh, user redirected to a (random) link from an array of html pages. How to stop it from looping infinitely?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, refresh

I'm not so familiar with javascript so I got this code from a tutorial. It seems to work fine on the first refresh. But when I add the script to the other html pages to achieve the same effect, it loops infinitely.

```html
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        // Create an array of the links to choose from:
        var links = new Array();
        links[0] = "page1.html";
        links[1] = "page2.html";
        //links[2] = "";
        //links[3] = "http://www.apple.com/";

        function openLink() {
          // Chooses a random link:
          var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length);
          // Directs the browser to the chosen target:
          parent.location = links[i];
          return false;
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body onload="openLink();">
```

I want to be able to refresh from whichever page and have it automatically send me to another page/link chosen randomly from the array.

Answer (score 0):

It's doing what you told it to do. You're eventually going to have to add a page in there somewhere that doesn't direct to any other pages. Otherwise, where's it ever going to land? Try this, which will eventually end up at http://www.randojs.com/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Create an array of the links to choose from:
            var links = ["page1.html", "page2.html", "http://www.randojs.com/"]; //RANDOJS.COM DOESN'T REDIRECT TO OTHER PAGES

            function openLink() {
              // Chooses a random link:
              var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length);

              // Directs the browser to the chosen target:
              parent.location = links[i];

              return false;
            }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="openLink();"></body>
</html>
```

OR, if you read the randojs.com website and decide it's easier for you to use that than javascript's built-in Math.random() function, you can use it in your project like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://randojs.com/2.0.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Create an array of the links to choose from:
            var links = ["page1.html", "page2.html", "http://www.randojs.com/"]; //RANDOJS.COM DOESN'T REDIRECT TO OTHER PAGES

            function openLink() {
              // Directs the browser to the chosen target:
              parent.location = rando(links).value;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="openLink();"></body>
</html>
```

Both options will work. Rando.js is just something I like to use. It is not a requirement.

Comment: Also, "parent" is usually called "window". So instead of saying parent.location, you can say window.location if you so choose